# Nice Menu module for Drupal: Sub-sub menu overrides sub-menu. CSS issue

Tags: css, drupal-modules

On this page http://bit.ly/T3yJIH, Nice Menu module for drupal does not show sub-sub menu properly. You can see it if you go to the first item in the menu and then go for the first one in the sub-menu. (Facilities->Spring->Calendar) Calendar item shows inside of the Spring sub-menu. I have been playing with css, could not get it worked. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try updating your css like this:

```
nice-menu ul li ul {
     margin-left: 35px !important; 
}
```

just tried it in the Chrome inspector, and i think this should do the trick;